# Why isn't ".style n args" working in my TikZ pic?

Tags: tikz-pgf, optional-arguments

I suspect there's something simple and obvious that I'm missing, but honestly, it's not for lack of trying :-)

I've created a pic that draws a small [Hasse diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram). I've even succeeded in giving it optional arguments to specify the text associated with each of the elements in the diagram. Here's what I've got:

```latex
% Oh, by the way, a separate newbie problem...
% I need my labels (generally lower-case letters) to align on the same baseline.
% But I don't think I can just set the style of node,
% because I don't want to effect every node in my document,
% only those that are labels in my Hasse diagrams.
% My solution is to create this command.
\newcommand{\element}{node[text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex]}

\tikzset{
    pics/2+1/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{
    code={
        \draw (-.3,  .5) \element (a) {#1}
              (-.3, -.5) \element (b) {#2}
              ( .3, 0  ) \element (c) {#3};
        \draw (a) -- (b);
        }},
    pics/2+1/.default=$a$/$b$/$c$
}
```

I invoke it à la either

```latex
\pic at (6,0) {2+1};
```

or

```latex
\pic at (6,0) {2+1={$\alpha$/$\beta$/$\gamma$}};
```

and both calls work like a charm.

My tyro question is, why is it that this other approach doesn't work?

```latex
\tikzset{
    pics/2+1/.style n args={3} {
    code={
        \draw (-.3,  .5) \element (a) {#1}
              (-.3, -.5) \element (b) {#2}
              ( .3, 0  ) \element (c) {#3};
        \draw (a) -- (b);
        }},
    pics/2+1/.default={$a$}{$b$}{$c$}
}
```

When I invoke this second one à la

```latex
\pic at (6,0) {2+1={$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{$\gamma$}};
```

I get the error message

```
! Use of \pgfkeys@sp@b doesn't match its definition.
<argument> e
            very \tikz@shape \space node/.try
l.370 ...(6,0) {2+1={$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{$\gamma$}}
```

I've scoured the PGF manual *and* this site.
What simple detail have I missed?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide us with a complete minimal working example. Not many will know what `\element` is. **However**, the error comes from the space in `pics/2+1/.style n args={3} {`, use `pics/2+1/.style n args={3}{` without space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an excess space in your pic definition. More specifically,

```
pics/2+1/.style n args={3} {
```

needs to become

```
pics/2+1/.style n args={3}{
```

The following is a minimal working example that illustrates this

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    pics/2+1/.style n args={3}{% <- you had an excess space before the laste brace
    code={
        \draw (-.3,  .5) node (a) {#1}
              (-.3, -.5) node (b) {#2}
              ( .3, 0  ) node (c) {#3};
        \draw (a) -- (b);
        }},
    pics/2+1/.default={$a$}{$b$}{$c$}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (6,0) {2+1={$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{$\gamma$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**ADDENDUM**: If you wish to give the nodes in the `pic` some options, you can use styles. Here is one out of many possibilities.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{
    pics/2+1/.style n args={3}{% <- you had an excess space before the laste brace
    code={
        \draw[nodes=element,pic actions] (-.3,  .5) node (a) {#1}
              (-.3, -.5) node (b) {#2}
              ( .3, 0  ) node (c) {#3}
        (a) -- (b);
        }},
    pics/2+1/.default={$a$}{$b$}{$c$},
    element/.style={text height=1.1em,text depth=0.25ex}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (6,0) {2+1={$\alpha$}{$\beta$}{$\gamma$}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Of course, if you only need these option at this place, you could say

```
    \draw[nodes={text height=1.1em,text depth=0.25ex},pic actions] (-.3,  .5) node (a) {#1}
          (-.3, -.5) node (b) {#2}
          ( .3, 0  ) node (c) {#3}
    (a) -- (b);
```

instead. There are many more variations. `pic actions` is just to remind ourselves that one can steer the appearance of the pic from outside, here it is not really needed/used.

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed fix it. And sorry about `\element`, I should have either included its definition or replaced them with `node`. But that does raise another question. The definition is `\newcommand{\element}{node[text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex]}`, and I use it to keep my code clean. I don't want to set the `text height` and `depth` for very `node` for ever, so I needed some scope. Is there a better way?

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum You could still upgrade your question to become compilable (except for the issue you are discussing, of course). Then others like me could upvote it. It is generally easier to follow the the discussion if one has some otherwise working examples. As for your question on the dimensions, this is what styles are for. You could define `\tikzset{element/.style={text height=1.1em,text depth=0.25ex}}`, say, and then use `\draw[nodes=element] ...`. I'll add this to the answer.